# Set Filter option in Dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova, html-select

Am working with jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap for Android Devices.

Currently Am facing an useability issue. 
In My project ; I have a drop-down control which used for listing country lists

In Emulator ; I can filter countries by typing letters. Suppose i want to check the countries which started letter "U" i just need to type "U" in keyboard and that countries will be loaded. But In Mobile Devices I couldnt do that. So need to scroll until its reach letter U.
So Its hard to use.

In my code i used;

```
 <select data-role="none" class="form_select" id="coutry_pick_">

 </select>
```

When I searched I got some solutions by adding a text-box for filtering.
[Check Its Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VeLKW/2/)

But without using this text-box with Drop-down control; Is there any solution for that ???
Please Help... Currently I lost lot of hours for find a solution for this..

[image]

Comment: Is there any Plugin for that ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got its solution :-)
Try to use **Select2** or **Chosen**

Select2 is a jQuery based replacement for select boxes. It supports searching, remote data sets, and infinite scrolling of results.

For more details and Demo : check [**Select2**](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) or Try [**Chosen**](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Its implemented in our some projects and its works fine.